# get all contacts and get all type of number of single contact name

Tags: android, android-contacts

**get all types of a(single)contact**

> i m getting All Contact with All type of a single contact And i succeeded But When print innerlist(multiple type phone number contain) it print last added contact for according to the size of innerlist for that single contact.....(didn't get read example)

**example**

> for ex: Contact Name:ABC TYPES OF NUMBERS 3 MOBILE:123 , HOME:456 ,OFFICE:789  SO THIS CODE `for (int i = 0; i < numberlist.size(); i++) {
>                           Log.e("inner", numberlist.get(i).getName() + " number  " + numberlist.get(i).getNumber());
>                       }`
>
> Will print(thrice but same contact number) (inner,ABC  number  789);

**pojo class**

```
public class ContactClass extends RealmObject  {
    @PrimaryKey
    String id;
    String name;
    String number;
    RealmList<ContactClass> numberlist;

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }


    public ContactClass() {
    }

    public RealmList<ContactClass> getNumberlist() {
        return numberlist;
    }

    public void setNumberlist(RealmList<ContactClass> numberlist) {
        this.numberlist = numberlist;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**result i want**

> i want to save contact name and all type of numbers of that single name..

**code i have tried**

```
 public void loadContact() {
    //swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    RealmList<ContactClass> list = new RealmList<>();
    PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();


    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            RealmList<ContactClass> numberlist = new RealmList<>();
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            ContactClass contactClass = new ContactClass();
            contactClass.setId(id);
            contactClass.setName(name);
            if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {


                    String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    int type = pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                    //   Log.e("called", phoneNo + "  " + name + "  " + id);
                    switch (type) {

                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                            try {
                                if (phoneNo.equals("") || phoneNo != null) {
                                    contactClass.setNumber(phoneNo);
                                    Log.e("test", phoneNo + "  name   " + name+"  type  "+"home");
                                    numberlist.add(contactClass);
                                }


                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                            }


                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                            try {
                                if (phoneNo.equals("") || phoneNo != null) {
                                    contactClass.setNumber(phoneNo);
                                    Log.e("test", phoneNo + "  name   " + name+"  type  "+"mobile");
                                    numberlist.add(contactClass);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                            }


                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                            try {
                                if (phoneNo.equals("") || phoneNo != null) {
                                    contactClass.setNumber(phoneNo);
                                    Log.e("test", phoneNo + "  name   " + name+"  type  "+"work");
                                    numberlist.add(contactClass);
                                }


                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                            }

                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_FAX_HOME:
                            try {
                                if (phoneNo.equals("") || phoneNo != null) {
                                    contactClass.setNumber(phoneNo);
                                    Log.e("test", phoneNo + "  name   " + name+"  type  "+"eaxhome");
                                    numberlist.add(contactClass);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                            }

                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_FAX_WORK:
                            try {
                                if (phoneNo.equals("") || phoneNo != null) {
                                    contactClass.setNumber(phoneNo);
                                    Log.e("test", phoneNo + "  name   " + name+"  type  "+"faxwork");
                                    numberlist.add(contactClass);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                            }

                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MAIN:
                            try {
                                if (phoneNo.equals("") || phoneNo != null) {
                                    contactClass.setNumber(phoneNo);
                                    Log.e("test", phoneNo + "  name   " + name+"  type  "+"main");
                                    numberlist.add(contactClass);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                            }

                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
                            try {

                                if (phoneNo.equals("") || phoneNo != null) {
                                    contactClass.setNumber(phoneNo);
                                    Log.e("test", phoneNo + "  name   " + name+"  type  "+"home");
                                    numberlist.add(contactClass);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                            }

                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM:
                            try {
                                if (phoneNo.equals("") || phoneNo != null) {
                                    contactClass.setNumber(phoneNo);
                                    Log.e("test", phoneNo);
                                    numberlist.add(contactClass);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                            }

                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_PAGER:
                            try {
                                if (phoneNo.equals("") || phoneNo != null) {
                                    contactClass.setNumber(phoneNo);
                                    Log.e("test", phoneNo);
                                    numberlist.add(contactClass);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                            }

                            break;
                    }
                }
                pCur.close();

               /* HashSet<ContactClass> h = new HashSet<>();
                h.addAll(numberlist);
                numberlist.clear();
                numberlist.addAll(h);*/
                contactClass.setNumberlist(numberlist);
                list.add(contactClass);
                for (int i = 0; i < numberlist.size(); i++) {
                    Log.e("inner", numberlist.get(i).getName() + " number  " + numberlist.get(i).getNumber());
                }

            }//1637

        }
        // saveToRealm(list);
       /* try {
            HashSet hs = new HashSet();

            hs.addAll(list); // demoArrayList= name of arrayList from which u want to remove duplicates
            List<ContactClass> classList = new ArrayList<>();
            list.clear();
            classList.addAll(hs);
            saveToRealm(classList);
            Log.e("resize", classList.size() + "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("savetorealm", "catch  " + e.toString());
        }*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a contact has 2 or more phone numbers, you'll be creating multiple `ContactClass` for the same contact.

Try changing your main loop to this:

```
// this loop iterates once per contact
while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
        RealmList<ContactClass> numberlist = new RealmList<>();
        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

        // create a new ContactClass just once per contact
        ContactClass contactClass = new ContactClass();
        contactClass.setId(id);
        contactClass.setName(name);

        Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{id}, null);
        // this loop iterates once per phone for each contact
        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {

            String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            int type = pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
            Log.e("called", phoneNo + "  " + name + "  " + id);
            switch (type) {
                ...
            }
        }
        pCur.close();

        // add the new ContactClass just once per contact to list
        contactClass.setNumberlist(numberlist);
        list.add(contactClass);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberlist.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("numbersize", numberlist.get(i).getNumber() + numberlist.get(i).getName() + numberlist.size() + "");
        }

    }
}
```